# Should the shaliach tzibbur wear a talis to say the 13 middos ?

Tags: halacha, chazzan-prayer-leader, tallit-gadol, selichot, sources-mekorot

The Gemoro in [Rosh Hashono 17b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l24.htm)  says that HKB”H put on a talis like a shaliach tzibbur and taught Moshe the 13 middos and said whenever Israel sins they should perform before Me according to this order (which we understand to be repeating the 13 middos) and I will forgive them. Are there any authorities who infer that for saying the 13 middos the shaliach tzibbur should wear a talis?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15082&st=&pgnum=166

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [*Taame Haminhagim* 681](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=315) says (with my own translation):

> טעם שהש״ץ מתעטף בציצית כשמשכימין לסליחות אע״פ שאין זמן ציצית, משום דאיתא, הקב״ה נתעטף בציצית כש״ץ והרגיל למרע״ה י״ג מדות, אלמא כשאומר י״ג מדות יתעטף בציצית
>
> The reason the *shatz* (leader) wraps himself in *tzitzis* when we arise early for *s'lichos* although it's not yet the hour for *tzitzis* is that it says "God wrapped himself in *tzitzis* like a *shatz* and accustomed *Moshe* to the thirteen traits": thus, when he says the thirteen traits, he should wrap himself in *tzitzis*.

(However, the footnote there cites other reasons the *shatz* should do so, and other views as to whether he should.)

Comment: Thank you. Can we assume the same would apply at a weekday mincha, Nusach Sefard, where they say 13 middos as part of techanun?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, I don't know. [You can ask. `:-)`](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score -1):

The minhag at Yeshivat Har Etzion is for the Ba'al Keriyah to cover his head with his tallit when reading the aliyah that contains the 13 middot (say, on a fast day).

Comment: Do you know their source?