# To say the 13 midos in "tachanun" weekday mincha, should the Sha"tz wear a tallis?

Tags: halacha, chazzan-prayer-leader, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer, chol-weekday

I asked the [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/should-the-shaliach-tzibbur-wear-a-talis-to-say-the-13-middos/13907#comment24771_13907) "The Gemoro in Rosh Hashono 17b says that HKB”H put on a talis like a shaliach tzibbur and taught Moshe the 13 middos and said whenever Israel sins they should perform before Me according to this order (which we understand to be repeating the 13 middos) and I will forgive them. Are there any authorities who infer that for saying the 13 middos the shaliach tzibbur should wear a talis?" and accepted an answer that said yes for selichos at a time not yet appropriate for tzitzis.

So now I would like to know please, can we assume the same would apply at a weekday mincha, Nusach Sefard, where they say 13 middos as part of tachanun? (Mostly I see that the Sha"Tz in Nusach Sefard shuls does not wear a tallis at a weekday mincha.)

Comment: Most Sefard Shuls also do not say Tachanun at Mincha.

Comment: @gershongold Huh?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kitzur Shulachan Aruch 128:6  ואם אין בנמצא טלית כלל, יכולין לומר סליחות ושלש עשרה מידות גם בלא טלית which means that you can say Shlosh Esrei Midos if necessary without a Talis.

Comment: Nice to know, but I don't see how this answers the question, which is whether the _shatz_ should wear a _talis_ for _mincha_ if saying the thirteen _midos_ (assuming one's available).

Comment: Thank you. So if we can extend from Selichos to Mincha in a Nusach Sefard Shul where they do say Tachanun, the Sha"Tz should wear a tallis if one is to be found.